# Extract column from tabular data

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

My task is to pull a column out of table and write down its length `len ()`. But my code is emitting it into a column, which is why `len ()` counts each element of the column separately, and not their total

```
water = water.readlines()
for col in water:
    el = list(col.split()[2])
```

water.txt:

```
     HETATM    1  H   HOH A   1      27.265  36.739  58.126
     HETATM    2  H   HOH A   1      27.109  35.124  57.944                          
     HETATM    3  O   HOH A   1      27.486  35.958  57.542
...
     HETATM 9999  O   HOH A3333      30.490  83.899  10.929
```

Desired intermediary output:

```
H
H
O
H
H
O
```

Comment: show what is `water`

Comment: @Tom Wojcik sorry, edited

Comment: what is the `map(str,...)` for? `str.split()` elements are already `str`?

Comment: @Xtrem532 you are right, changed. But how does this help?

Comment: Simpler code is easier to read. Do you have a longer example for `water.txt`? I don't see how a column length can be different from line-count.

Comment: Use a print command to see what the results are that you are getting with your code. What you think are columns are likely rows. Also please state an example of your desired output.

Comment: then there is a repetition of these three lines, and `END` at the end. There are 9999 lines in total. I need to know the length of a column. How many elements are in it.

Comment: @roadrunner66 yeah, you are right, these are just strings! How can I glue them into one line?

Comment: Do you know what program this came from?  I'm pretty sure I've seen this file format before (I think it's from a spectrometer or something?)  I'm pretty sure there are already Python libraries for it but I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly extracting the colum. The correct way is with a list comprehension:

```
with open(...) as water:
    el = [line.split()[2] for line in water]
```

With your sample data, I get `['H', 'H', 'O']` for el, which is the third column.

Comment: this works but only with the first column.   When I try to put 1 or more:
`line 3, in <listcomp>
    el = [line.split()[1] for line in water2]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Very concise solution.  A `list comprehension` is a shortcut that a new user would be better advised to implement step by step in more traditional code, as it hides the ideas he/she is supposed to understand.

Answer (score 1):

For the future you'll likely use other means to import data in tabular form. But this is an important exercise, because the following will apply to most issues you will face. `The most important initial concept is to use plenty of print statements to understand what each step does.`

```
file = "HETATM    1  H   HOH A   1      27.265  36.739  58.126\nHETATM    2  H   HOH A   1      27.109  35.124  57.944\nHETATM    3  O   HOH A   1      27.486  35.958  57.542\n"
        
lines=file.split('\n')
print(lines)
```

output is a list of strings:

```
['HETATM    1  H   HOH A   1      27.265  36.739  58.126',
 'HETATM    2  H   HOH A   1      27.109  35.124  57.944',
 'HETATM    3  O   HOH A   1      27.486  35.958  57.542',
 '']
```

Each line is now still a string, so you need to turn it into a list
for example:

```
a=lines[2].split()
print(a)
```

output is a list of strings, each string one column value for this particular line/row:

```
['HETATM', '3', 'O', 'HOH', 'A', '1', '27.486', '35.958', '57.542']
```

To do that for every line and keep the 3rd column (index 2):

```
col2=[]  # make an empty list to hold the column

for l in lines:
    if len(l)>1:      # leaves empty lines, also at end of file 
        cols=l.split()
        col2.append(cols[2])


print(col2)
```

output is a list representing your 2nd column

`['H', 'H', 'O']`

Because Python is used with many packages that do a lot in a single line, and also because of duck-typing, it is more important than in other languages to always know what the result of your last line is, both in type and in meaning.

In the future you will likely use `numpy` or `pandas` to read in tabular data in a single line. But to understand that single line can sometimes be hard. It is also hard to memorize.  Doing it yourself in low level code as shown above will help you stay connected to your code. It will also help you to read how other people implemented higher level functions.